# Image slider using jquery with prev and next button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I would like to make image slider with prev and next button using jquery. I am new to jquery so i posted my html code, so anyone give me the relevant jquery code to me..

```
<div class="slide">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <img src="image.png"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="image.png"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="image.png"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="image.png"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="image.png"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="image.png"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="image.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you know we do not provide _from-scratch_ code here

Comment: scratch code? @moffeltje

Comment: aka, did you try anything before asking?

Comment: @Mahi Yes, you should not expect us to write full working code for you

Comment: @Masiorama  i tried it in bootstrap carousal and it is working fine., but i'm new to jquery that's why...

Comment: @Mahi Well, follow some tutorials, understand jquery and search for the things you want on google, so you can make it yourself ;)